# Unable to Post JSON data to OData WEBAPI Service Action

Tags: angularjs, web-services, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I am trying consume my OData Action and trying to post a JSON Data as:

```
{
  "contractId":[1,3,5,7,9],
  "projectId":9
}
```

My Action is configured as :

```
var deleteContracts = builder.EntityType<Contract>().Collection.Action("DeleteItems").Returns<HttpResponseMessage>();
deleteContracts.CollectionParameter<long>("C_Id");
deleteContracts.Parameter<long>("P_Id");
```

Action is as below:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteItems (ODataActionParameters param)
 {
    //DO something
    return null;
 }
```

While I am trying to call this, I am getting the following issue:

> "error": {
>              "code": "",
>            "message": "The request entity's media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is not supported for this resource.",
>              "innererror": {
>              "message": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'ODataActionParameters' from content with media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.",
>              "type": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
>              "stacktrace": " at  System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
>          }
>       }

Response header:

```
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
```

Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Odata-Version: 4.0
X-Sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcbG1pc2hyYVxEb2N1bWVudHNcTGF4bWlrYW50XF9wcm9qZWN0c1xXZWJcRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnRcQ29udHJhY3RzXEluRWlnaHQuQ29udHJhY3RzLldlYlNlcnZpY2VzXG9kYXRhLWNvbnRyYWN0c1xDb250cmFjdHNcRGVmYXVsdC5EZWxldGVTZWxlY3RlZENvbnRyYWN0?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 04:45:35 GMT
Content-Length: 786

Request Header:

```
POST /ContractsWebServices/ContractsWebService/odata-contracts/Contracts/Default.DeleteItems HTTP/1.1
```

HOST: localhost:65314
content-type: application/json
content-length: 50

{
  "contractId":[1,3,5,7,9],
  "projectId":9
}

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuget doesn't resolve oData dlls version properly. in project Odata version for routing was v2/3 but implementation was done for newly added controller as per v4.

Answer (score 1):

What is in your HTTP request header?

You should add following in the header to indicate the request format.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Edited:

Two things to note:

1. Do not use HttpResponseMessage as response type, or the metadata would look weird. Just use the actual entity or primitive type you want to return, can leave it empty if nothing returned
2. The parameter name does not match:
   contractId->C_Id, projectId->P_Id

But based on the message, the issue is still in wrong header being sent.

Please try following code:

```
namespace wea1
{
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Web.OData;
    using System.Web.OData.Builder;
    using System.Web.OData.Extensions;

    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            var deleteContracts = builder.EntityType<Contract>().Collection.Action("DeleteItems").Returns<int>();
            deleteContracts.CollectionParameter<long>("contractId");
            deleteContracts.Parameter<long>("projectId");

            builder.EntitySet<Contract>("Contracts");
            config.MapODataServiceRoute("r1", "r1", builder.GetEdmModel());
        }
    }

    public class Contract { public int Id { get; set; } }

    public class ContractsController : ODataController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteItems([FromBody]ODataActionParameters param)
        {
            return Ok(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Request:

```
POST http://localhost:57071/r1/Contracts/Default.DeleteItems HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:57071
Content-Length: 50

{
  "contractId":[1,3,5,7,9],
  "projectId":9
}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Content-Length: 82

{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:57071/r1/$metadata#Edm.Int32","value":2
}
```

Comment: I have already used Content Type as application/json and there authentication header too.

Comment: @Laxmikant Except that it is saying that your content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: I do agree, so I have already used Content Type as application/json. Even I tried another endpoint in another controller it is working

Comment: Can you put the whole request and response header in the question? authentication related entries could be ignored.

Comment: added in Question

Comment: Actually i am able  to consume odata service from another controller, but  only one of controller httppost action invoking with the data (json data)